# Oracle Resource manager

Tags: oracle, resources

I am doing a `POC` on `Oracle Resource Manager`. I have created the plan, consumer groups etc. I am able to see the RESOURCE MANAGER Groups in SESSION monitor and other `Oracle` views. However, I am not able to fetch the concrete stats(effct on SGA/PGA/CPU/PARALLEL THREADS etc) to conclude the `POC`. I tried checking the stats in `AWR` too but could not find anthing helpful. Is there any menthod/View which can be leveraged for this info? Is there any `Oracle` table/view that reocrds the session sepcific information on CPU `Count/SGA/PGA`
I have tried the below views:

```
select * from V$RSRC_PLAN;
select name,pqs_completed,pq_servers_used from V$RSRC_CONSUMER_GROUP;
select * from V$RSRC_SESSION_INFO;
select * from V$RSRC_PLAN_HISTORY;
select * from V$RSRCMGRMETRIC;
```

Comment: `V$SESSION` would show that information in real time, but not historical data. Also, my experience is that you won't see any specific effect of a resource plan until the system resources are at or near 100% utilization. Enforcement doesn't happen until the highest priority users begin to see a bottleneck. I would think you'd need some sort of benchmark test to run that could demonstrate different behaviors of the system under load, with and without the resource plan in place.

Comment: @pmdba I can generate load to reach the 100% utilization and will tr to see the effect. Few Questions- 
If system has just P2 processes with consumption at 100% and some p1 process kicks in how Oracle will get the resources for p1? Can this information be checked in any oracle views?